# Can owls, cats and others visual nocturnal animals see in moonless nights?

Tags: biology, fauna, day-night, vision

Im working in a moonless xeno planet and i want nocturnal creatures. I have  animals that use smell, ear and touch, but im not sure about vision. I mean, animals and persons need a tiny bit of light to see in the darkness, we cant see in total darkness, so i dont know if nocturnal animals who use vision to hunt and move can work in a planet where every night is moonless (in Earth we have 1 moonless night per month, so no big deal here). Some help? There is no problem with moonless nights? they will need some infrared/termic vision? Thanks.

Comment: Living in  the countryside, I've found that starlight is quite adequate for human vision. Try it, allow 20 minutes for your eyes to adapt and you'll see.

Comment: *Humans* can see well enough by starlight alone to avoid falling into holes or bumping into fences and houses. We have quite good night vision for a diurnal animal. And on Earth, about half of night time is moonless, ranging from the whole night at new Moon to none at full Moon -- most of the time, the Moon is visible for part of the night and invisible for the other part of the night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to see on moonless nights.

For the last few years my bedrooms have been almost totally dark when I turn off the lights to go to sleep.  Everything looks like a very, very dark gray almost totally black.

But if I wake up after a while I find that my eyes have adapted to the dark, whether they were open or closed, and I can see many different shades of gray and see where all the furnituare is and everything.

I used to walk up a hill to a field to look at the stars with binoculars, and moonless nights would be the best for that.  And I could see well enough to walk up the hill safely.

The new moon has an apparent magnitude of - 2.50, the full moon has an apparent magnitude of -12.90, which is over 10,000 times brighter.

The total integrated magnitude of the night sky is listed as -6.5, which is 4 magnitudes or about 39.8 times as bright as the light of a new moon.  The light of fhe night sky comes from the stars and from air glow, and other  factors.  Anyway, on Earth the total light from the night sky is usually many times the total light from a new moon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude

If there is an advanced civilization on your planet, there could be light pollution,  drowning out the starlight with artificial light refected downwards from clouds and air pollution onto the surface for miles around cities and towns, and making it much easier for animals to see at night.

Remember than many animals have much better night vision than humans do.  So nocturnal animals on your world should have simply evolved better night vision than nocturnal animals on Earth.

And on Earth there are bioluminsecent fungi which glow in the dark.  If your planet has a lot more of them for some reason, there may be more light for animals to see with, even in caverns or dense forests when the light from the sky is blocked.

And of course there are also some animals, mostly deep see ones, which glow.

And of course on Earth all objects at normal temperatures glow in the infrared bands. And some animals can sense or even see infrared light.  That would be especially useful for predators seeking warm blooded prey.

So I think that nocturnal animals can use vision during the darker nights of your moonless world.

Comment: Humans can see pretty well by starlight alone -- I have experience with this as well (dark sky site star parties).  Cats can see many times better in low light.  Owls mostly don't even need to see to locate prey (though it's very helpful for their navigation, especially to return to a branch perch).

Comment: Thanks :D, this is a very complete answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search would have informed you that cats are not too bothered by *completely* moonless nights (1 out of every 28 days). Same goes for owl and other nocturnal, simply because having new moon is a regular occurence on Earth.

It of course depends on the amount of starlight your world receive. In a completely dark world, obviously, night vision is not gonna help you at all.

Comment: That would be about 14 out of 28 nights, but of course the moonless time is shared among all 28 nights. Half of the time the Moon is above the horizon the Sun is also above the horizon. The only night when the Moon shines all night is the night of the full Moon. (Which you should have already known from direct experience; the Moon is quite easy to see in daytime when it is not very close to the Sun.)

Comment: I stupidly assumed that if they were not bothered by the new moon, they wouldn't be bothered by Moon course the other 27 days, nor varying illuminations above that level.